# How can i save spectrogram of audio file (.wav) from folders and sub-folders?

Tags: python, audio, wav, spectrogram

I have 276 audio file (.wav). I want to plot signal and spectrogram together like following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as  plot
from scipy.io import wavfile

samplingfrequency, signaldata = wavfile.read('/home/narges/dataset/seri1.16khz.128kbps/Voice Recorder/N00xxxx/N000200.wav')

plot.subplot(211)
plot.title('spec of vowel')

plot.plot(signaldata)
plot.xlabel('sample')
plot.ylabel('amp')

plot.subplot(212)
plot.specgram(signaldata,Fs=samplingfrequency)
plot.xlabel('time')
plot.ylabel('freq')

plot.show()
```

But i want to read all folders and sub-folders. I use this code for reading all folders and sub-folders:

```
path = Path('/home/narges/dataset/dataset-CV-16kHz-128kbps/train/').glob('**/*.wav')
wavs = [str(wavf) for wavf in path if wavf.is_file()]
wavs.sort()
```

And i'm using this code for saving Speaker ID:

number_of_files=len(wavs)
   spk_ID = [wavs[i].split('/')[-1].lower() for i in range(number_of_files)]

Now, how can i change following code for read all of my .wav file in directory (path) and plot signal and spectrogram (like first code), and save it with the name of spk_ID?

```
def graph_spectrogram(wav_file):
    wavs = rate, data = wavfile.read('/home/narges/dataset/dataset-CV-16kHz-128kbps/train/speaker_00/s_00_0_00.wav')
    pxx, freq, bins, im = plt.specgram(x=data, Fs=rate, noverlap=384, NFFT=512)
    spk_ID = [wavs.split('/')[-1].lower()]
    plt.xlabel('time')
    plt.ylabel('freq')
    plt.savefig('xyz.png',bbox_inches='tight', dpi=300, frameon='false')

if __name__=='__main__':
   graph_spectrogram('...')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this code and it's correct, if any one want to use:

```
from pathlib import Path
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
from scipy.io import wavfile

path = Path('/home/narges/dataset/dataset-CV-16kHz-128kbps/train/').glob('**/*.wav')
wavs = [str(wavf) for wavf in path if wavf.is_file()]
wavs.sort()

number_of_files=len(wavs)

spk_ID = [wavs[i].split('/')[-1].lower() for i in range(number_of_files)]

for i in range(number_of_files):
    samplingfrequency, signaldata = wavfile.read(wavs[i])
    pxx, freq, bins, im = plot.specgram(x=signaldata, Fs=samplingfrequency, noverlap=384, NFFT=512)
    plot.title('spec of vowel')
    plot.xlabel('time')
    plot.ylabel('freq')
    plot.savefig("spk_ID:{}.png".format(spk_ID[i]), bbox_inches='tight', dpi=300, frameon='false')
```